# jQuery Hide using ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the border color of an image using its id with jquery
( photo['id'] is passed in from a previous function )
the ids of the photos are of the form 'photo239839'

```
 $('#photo'+photo['id']+'').click(function(){  
       $('#photo'+photo['id']+'').css('border-color','#777');

    });
```

When I try to use this same code using its class it works,
but I can't use this method since there are multiple images on the same
page with the same class

```
$('img.flickr_photo').click(function() {
    $("this.flickr_photo").css('border-color','#777');
});
```

Comment: I'd like to see the HTML involved to ensure the CSS selector is accurate.

Comment: have you tried this http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/hide ?? you can use the 'img.flickr_photo as selector.

Answer (score 18):

This is what you need to do:

```
$('img.flickr_photo').click(function(){  
       $(this).css('border-color','#777');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I would always always add a css class rather than an inline style.
Much more maintainable and extensible.

Example:

```
$('img.flickr_photo').click(function(){  
       $(this).addClass('greyishBorder');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Either photo['id'] is wrong, or is changing after you set up the click handler.

To test for the first case, you can alert (or console.log with FireBug, or whatever) the length of the jQuery selection:

```
alert($('#photo'+photo['id']).length);
```

The solution in the second case is to use 'this'. In the click handler, 'this' is set to the element that caused the click event.

```
$('#photo'+photo['id']).click(function(){  
   $(this).css('border-color','#777');
});
```

**Edit:** @Dreas Grech is right, as long as you want to apply the behavior to all the elements with the flickr_photo class. If you can generalize the selector to select *all* the elements with a single query, it's better to do that.